# Need WPF Design Ideas For A New Application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wpf-controls, binding

I have to build several WPF screens which has many editable fields. There is a separate business object (view model) that I get to create the views along with the set of rules For every screen, I get a list of rules which apply to some of those fields, which defines things like if it is editable, default value, list of values it shud display. .

Firstly,I am just thinking to generate the views by data templating the corresponding business object for that view. I need some ideas on how to validate these rules or apply these kind of rules to the properties in the bussiness object. Hopefully, I am clear what I have mentioned above.

I am looking for some design ideas, WPF OOB features if any, common paterns or frameworks, for scenarios such as these. Any such idea would be of help.

Thanks, Mani

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [the Silverlight DataForm that was ported to WPF](http://wpfdataform.codeplex.com/)